# Mongo db reference duplicate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this error i cannot seem to understand what I'm doing wrong.

In my database i have an object called Question, questions have a reference to Subject and to User. When I'm trying to post to Question i get a strange error.

```
E11000 duplicate key error index: codenoname.questions.$subject.name_1 dup key: { : null }
```

My Question schema:

```
var questionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type : String , required : true},
    text: { type : String , required : true},
    subject: {type:String, ref: 'Subject', required: true},
    createdBy: {type: String, ref:'User', required: true},
    difficulty: { type : String , required : true},
    alternatives: [{alternative: {type:String, required:true}, isCorrect: {type:Boolean, required:true}}]
});
```

and my Subject

```
var subjectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type : String , required : true, unique:true}
});
```

Save method:

```
var question = new Question(
            {title: title, 
             text: text, 
             subject: ObjectId(subject), 
             difficulty: difficulty, 
             createdBy: id,
             alternatives:alternatives
            });
        question.save( function(err, newQuestion) {
            if(err)  {
                res.status(400).json({err:err});
            } else {
                res.status(200).json({status:"Question added"});
            }
        });
```

**What i have tried**

1. Delete all Questions, then I can post, but just one...
2. Remove the reference and just keep it as a string. No difference.
3. Restarted the server a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `unique: true` from subject. I think questionSchema inherits the unique property and once you try to save two different questions with the same subject, you'll get duplicate key.

Follow these steps:

1. Remove `unique: true` from your model
2. Find the index name by typing `db.questions.getIndexes()` in your terminal.
3. Remove it by typing `db.questions.dropIndex(name)` where `name` is the `"name"`-property from step 2

Example from my database where i'll remove the unique-property from usernames:

```
> db.accounts.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "passport_local_mongoose_express4.accounts"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "email" : 1
        },
        "name" : "email_1",
        "ns" : "passport_local_mongoose_express4.accounts",
        "background" : true
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "username" : 1
        },
        "name" : "username_1",
        "ns" : "passport_local_mongoose_express4.accounts",
        "background" : true
    }
]


> db.accounts.dropIndex('username_1')
```

Comment: The name is now equal to `_id_` instead of `name`, but i receive the same error.

Comment: I saw i had a index on the subject.name property on the Question object! Thank you!